# Looping through an json request Alexa skill

Tags: python, aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit

I seem to be having an issue with looping through the data that I pulled from a url in my Alexa skill, here is my sample code:

```
def get_elevator_status():
session_attributes = {}
card_title = "Septa Elevator Status"
reprompt_text = ""
should_end_session = False


response = urllib2.urlopen(API_BASE_URL + "/elevator")
septa_elevator_status = json.load(response) 


for elevators in septa_elevator_status['results']:
    speech_output = "The following elevators are out of service." "On " + elevators['line'] + " at station " + elevators['station'] + " the " + elevators['elevator'] + " elevator has " + elevators['message']
```

If I run the code in python shell and print out the results (if there are multiple outages) it prints out all lines. But when I test my Alexa skill and ask for outages it only reports back one result even though there are multiple elevator outages. Am I missing something for this to work? Should this code loop through and say all results found right?

Answer (score 0):

can you post the 'response' json, my guess is that the json is not formed correctly

Answer (score 0):

While looping through the result set everytime you are overwriting `speech_output` with that particular `elevators`. Instead, you have to concatenate every result to `speech_output`.

```
for elevators in septa_elevator_status['results']:
    speech_output =  speech_output  + " <s> The following elevators are out of service." "On " + elevators['line'] + " at station " + elevators['station'] + " the " + elevators['elevator'] + " elevator has " + elevators['message'] + "</s>"
```

`<s>` is the sentence tag, use it only if you are using SSML.